# How to check if a remote server is up through a proxy?

Tags: proxy, ansible, squid, ping

I have a series of lab linux server (centos/rh) that are built using an automated PXE install via kickstart file.  I would like to use another automated process (ansible) to monitor when the installations have completed.  Normally I would use a simple tool like `ping` but these servers can only be accessed remotely through an internal proxy.

One idea was to add httpd and a simple index.html page via the kickstart, then use `curl` to loop over requesting the page.  While this will work, it seems pretty heavy for such a simple check and then requires the extra step of removing all this baggage afterwards.

I understand that ping can't operate at this level in the stack, but is there a way to accomplish something like:

```
ping labhost --proxy 192.168.0.2:3128
```

Comment: it sounds like I might want an ssh bastion, I'm reading up on them now!

Answer (score 0):

Allow ssh from the host running Ansible to the new instance. Either directly routed, or through something like a ssh bastion in front of it with `ProxyJump`. You will need to know an initial credential, so install a ssh key with the kickstart.

Add the host to inventory and run a play on it.  `wait_for_connection` module will attempt to connect to it several times.  The play will need  `gather_facts: False` to skip the implicit gathering of host information, as it is not reachable to start.

Ansible's `ping` module is not ICMP echo. It remotes into the box, ssh by default, and gets a simple response back.

---

ICMP is a feature of IP, at a different layer than TCP or UDP. Does not make much sense to proxy an ICMP packet beyond where an IP packet would go.